# User script to auto flag NLN (no longer needed) comments

Tags: script, comments

### Screenshot

[image: nln-true]

### About

The user script uses multiple search keyword combinations via RegEx to catch NLN (no longer needed) comments and send them to the chat room. Currently, the script is running in [this room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232981/shrees-room).

### License

[MIT](https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT.html)

### Code

Written in JavaScript, uses jQuery. [Github link](https://github.com/sri-shree/nlncomment)

### Platform

Install the script with a script manager like [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/). Auto Flag requires write access, so you need to provide your access token, access key, and `roomid` (where you want to send a message).

### Contact

Issues, complaints, and ideas should be posted here or on [Github](https://github.com/sri-shree/nlncomment/issues).

<sub>**Note: For access token / access key , follow [this URL](https://stackapps.com/questions/9345/how-can-i-quickly-get-an-access-token-for-personal-use)**</sub>

Comment: (About) how accurate is this in its current form? And what would you recommend doing to increase it if I want it to be more accurate if I want to set this up on my account

Comment: Wow! thats impressive. And running for a year and a half. Thats way more acute then I would want it to be. Im going to need to set this up