# PLACEHOLDER - NLN comment bot

Tags: app, placeholder

This bot is going into beta as a proof of concept soon once a bug in ChatExtange (chat library I'm using) is fixed or a work around is solves.

This bot will detect and auto-flag comments that may be NLN. The current code can be viewed [in this GH repo](https://github.com/not-a-ethan/nlnCommentBot) but may be out of date due to me not actively committing to it.

Took inspiration from [4b0's userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/8945/91014).

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you commit `:/node_modules` on purpose? You already have package-lock.json in there.

Comment: @starball im going to be using Replit to host it so I have been coding there and I just committed all the files without excluding any since it does not matter since all the secret stuff are stored in environment vars

Comment: `node_modules` doesn't tend to contain any secret things as far as I'm aware, though I think some specific build tools like to store cache info in there IIRC. Does `node_modules` need to be committed for the replit to work? (I have never used it before). In general cases, committing `node_modules` can consume a lot of storage on your git repo host, and adds significantly to the time needed to clone the repo. If that's not relevant here, then that's fine.

Comment: @starball I was saying that node modules **dont** contain anything secret so there's no downside in committing. And I don't know. For this project Im coding directly in Replit so I don't want to change anything even though there is a history so I can rollback to a past version.